# Cannot fetch BLOB field from PostgreSQL with Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, blob, hibernate-criteria

I have a BLOB field in my PostGreSQL and i am trying to fetch this field using hibernate. Below is a snapshot of the same:

**Table**

[image]

Now i want to fetch this field and show it to the user. To do this, i have used a `byte[]` array. Below is my code:

**entity.java**

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "MAIL_BODY",length=100000)
public Byte[] getMailBody() {
    return mailBody;
}
public void setMailBody(Byte[] mailBody) {
    this.mailBody = mailBody;
}
```

**service.java**

```
Session session=comTtEflMailDataServiceDao.getCurrentSessionPortal();
Criterion criterion=Restrictions.eq("headerSeqNo", "40011532018");
comTtEflMailData=comTtEflMailDataServiceDao.getListByFilter(criterion, session);
```

**DAO.java**

```
criteria = currSession.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
System.out.println(3);
criteria.add(criterion);
System.out.println(2);
resultset = (T) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

However, when i run the code, i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that this exception is related to the `BLOB` field reading? Could you please provide the full stack trace and all related to the query entity's fields.

Comment: @SternK I solved the issue. and you're right. it wasn't due to the BLOB field. Thanks